# How to use Boolean in Add function of JsonObject

Tags: java, json

I would like to construct a Json in main method.
I have a Boolean variable in my Json.

```
For example:
{"type": "AAA",
 "isForm": true
}
```

Code is the following:

```
JsonObject json = Json.createObjectBuilder()
    .add("type", "AAA")
    .add("isForm", true)
    .build()
```

I got this error:

```
javax.json.JsonValue$2 cannot be cast to javax.json.JsonString
```

How can create my Json with a varaible value is a Boolean ?
Thank you

Comment: Docs says it does https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObjectBuilder.html#add-java.lang.String-boolean-

Comment: Check the example in Docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObjectBuilder.html, I never used it, but it does a Factory call before, maybe it makes difference in some way.

Comment: It should work and I can also run the code without Exception. @Dom which version/dependencies are you using? Are you sure that the pasted code causes the exception?

Comment: Thanks for you all, I resolved it by following the Docs.